# Xcode GCDAsyncSocket telnet connection

Tags: ios, xcode, telnet, gcdasyncsocket

I'm having trouble getting started with GCDAsyncSocket to use a telnet connection.
When I connect through terminal I get some text and it asks me to login.
With GCDAsyncSocket I can get a connection but can't get any text from it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);

    socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSError *err = nil;
    if (![socket connectToHost:@"192.168.1.1" onPort:23 error:&err])
    {
        // If there was an error, it's likely something like "already connected" or "no delegate set"
        NSLog(@"I goofed: %@", err);
    }
    [socket readDataWithTimeout:5 tag:1];
}
```

.

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)port {
    NSLog(@"Cool, I'm connected! That was easy.");

}
```

.

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    NSString *responce = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"responce=%@",responce);
}
```

data responds with fffd01ff fd1ffffb 01fffb03

response is always null.

Comment: You should read the telnet [RFCs](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html)! A data sequence beginning with `0xff` are special telnet commands.

Comment: It seems to be more a timing issue I think, as sometimes I get the welcome text, sometime half of it, and sometimes none of it.

Comment: If I use readDataToLength: I can get the response, however I need to know the exact length of the response. If I don't know the length, how to I make it send me everything up to point where it's waiting for an input?

Comment: TCP in general, and telnet specifically, is just a stream of "characters". If you receive a special telnet command sequence initializer (0xff, also known as `IAC` or Interpret As Command) you have to read the next byte to know what command it is then you can (maybe, depending on command) know the length. For normal data, there is no set length. One way is to do a (non-blocking) read into a fixed-size buffer, and then extract commands and lines from that buffer. When you can't extract more commands/lines, you wait for more data to arrive and start over filling the buffer.

Comment: Do you have any example code to do a non-blocking read into a buffer?
I have figured out that I can get it working fine using the standard AsyncSocket (Not the GCD version) which runs line by line and pausing 1 second between commands I can read the whole output and respond.
Using the GCDAsyncSocket version, it sends the commands too quickly when the receiver is not ready for them

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't really know anything about Objective-C or iOS and its API.

Comment: I've found a solution :-) there's a method readDataToData which I thought put data into data but it doesn't, it reads data upto a data string you supply. So knowing the telnet session waits for each command with a colon then space, I just do readDataToData @": " and it reads it all.